# Django no reverse match for view in {% url %}

Tags: django

When using Django 2.0.3, I get the error

Reverse for 'detail_view' not found. 'detail_view' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

With this row highlighted in my template (results/list.html):

```
data-href="{% url 'detail_view' intron_id=hit.0 %}"
```

(If it matters, this line is in a {% for hit in results %} loop; I didn't include the rest of the html file because the tags were being displayed)

The main urls.py file is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from sitepages import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('about/', views.about, name="about"),
    path('results/', include('results.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

and the results app's urls.py file is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

app_name='results'

urlpatterns = [
    path('list', views.list),
    re_path('(?P<intron_id>\w+)/$', views.detail_view, name='detail_view'),
]
```

The views.py file for the results app is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import apsw
import re
from .models import Introns

#parse input from search bar and get requested info from database
def detail_view(request, id):
    conn = apsw.Connection('subset.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    #just get one example intron so that we can format the individual intron view page
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM introns WHERE id=?", id)
    data = cur.fetchall()
    return render(request, 'results/individual.html', {'data':data})

def list(request):
    #another view that returns results/list.html without errors if I try to navigate directly to it without giving it any data to display
```

Everyone with similar problems has had some typo in their urls.py or html file, but as far as I can tell, I don't have the common typos. Am I blind, or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to insert the app name in your link like:

```
data-href="{% url 'results:detail_view' intron_id=hit.0 %}"
```

this must work just fine

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include `intron_id`.  Django will place any variables in order

`data-href="{% url 'detail_view' hit.0 %}"`